# Can't do Git Push properly how to fix this

Tags: git, github

when I try `git push -u origin main` it gives me this message and warning

`Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void GitCredentialManager.CommandContext..ctor(System.String)'. at GitCredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args)`

and this warning

`warning: could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI'`

here somethings i did before appearing this problem

my git version is `git version 2.38.1.windows.1`. I'm using git/git hub for the first time.

first installed the `2.39.0` version but it gave me the problem `warning: could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI` and to fix this I installed `2.38` version.

I use proxy to access the internet and again this problem rises

`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXX/XXXXX.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443` to fix it I found a way on here which is `git config --global --add remote.origin.proxy "my-proxy:port"`

I have no idea what I did I just follow the instructions I hope this does not have a relation to the current issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same  `could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI'`. On another forum, someone suggest that downgrade gitbash to an older version would solve the issue, but then I get the  `Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:`  .

Delete gitbash, reinstall it. Do the usual :

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.mail
```

And problem solves

Answer (score 0):

Remove existing workspace and try to clone with ssh for E.g., **git clone repo** and do **git push**

Comment: Could you please share an explanation why this works and maybe links to the docs?